# How to concatenate two fields together in a Salesforce Flow Formula element?

Tags: visual-flows

I am trying to concatenate two field values together in a formula resource in Salesforce Flow however, despite seeming trivial, I can't get the syntax right to show the correct output. I have tried the following:

```
{!LoopedAccount.Country__c} & {!LoopedAccount.Name}
{!LoopedAccount.Country__c} + {!LoopedAccount.Name}
{!LoopedAccount.Country__c}{!LoopedAccount.Name}
```

None of which seem to be valid expressions at runtime with all returning nulls.

When simply adding either of the following:

```
{!LoopedAccount.Country__c} 
{!LoopedAccount.Name}
```

..these values show correctly.

Salesforce literature advises the & is the correct concatenation operator. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_considerations_design_formulas.htm&type=5

Flow variable syntax

Comment: & is the correct concatenation operator in the flow formula resource, have you tried adding a space between the 2 merged fields like this `{!LoopedAccount.Country__c} & ' ' & {!LoopedAccount.Name}` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just tried with the space, but still no luck!

Answer (score 1):

Best solution I have come up with is to assign the field values to a temporary variable and then in the formula element reference those temporary variables.

Step 1:
Assignment Element

```
{!tempAccountName} = {!LoopedAccount.Name}
{!tempCountry} = {!LoopedAccount.Country__c}
```

Step 2:
Formula element

```
{!tempCountry}&' '&{!tempAccountName}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a formula like this :)

```
{!LoopedAccount.Name+LoopedAccount.Operator__c}
```